# Table of contents not added in pdf format using ASPOSE WORD , java

Tags: java, pdf, ms-word, aspose, aspose.words

```
def gDataDir;

def index() {
    gDataDir = "/home/sithapa/gitProject/aposeWord/documents/basics/";
    topResultsTest();
}

def topResultsTest(){

    Document main_src = new Document(gDataDir + "cover_page_toc.docx");
    Document src3 = new Document(gDataDir + "our_testing_template.docx");

    def String[] fields = ["Heading1","Subtitle1","Subtitle2"];

    def Object[] values = ['This is a Heading','this is a subtitle1','\nthis is a subtitle2'];

    src3.getMailMerge().execute(fields, values);
    //Appending
    main_src.appendDocument(src3, ImportFormatMode.KEEP_SOURCE_FORMATTING);

    //Update the table of contents.
    main_src.updateFields();
    main_src.updatePageLayout();

    main_src.save(gDataDir + "final_output.docx");
    saveAsPDF(main_src)
}


def saveAsPDF(main_src){

    //Document src = new Document(gDataDir + "final_output.docx");

    //main_src.save(gDataDir + "simpleOpenSaveAsPDF_output.pdf", SaveFormat.PDF);
    main_src.save(gDataDir + "Document.Doc2PdfSave Out.pdf");

}
```

**Here the Table of contents is seen in .docx in a linux OS but not seen in Windows. TOC in pdf format is not seen in both OS.I have attached the required documents in this link:**
[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7qBJwMlTniCYUZBdWEwZFRFVHc/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2):

I noted that your headings are in the document header. Please move these to the document body.

These headings are not saved in the PDF by default. You need to specify these in an instance of PdfSaveOptions.

```
// Set 2 levels of headings to appear in PDF
PdfSaveOptions so = new PdfSaveOptions();
so.getOutlineOptions().setHeadingsOutlineLevels(2);

// Specify the save options as parameter
document.save("output.pdf", so);
```

[image: Headings are in document header]

I work for Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: Thank you, your code works but I explicitly want my headings in Header as I want them to appear in all the following pages. Is It possible for my headings in header to appear in the TOC both in pdf and docx.

Comment: Sorry, headings do not come in side bookmarks. This behavior is same in both MS Word and Aspose. The bookmarks point to one location, but if it comes in header (every page), that is not one location.